# Speed Up gganimate Rendering

Tags: r, multithreading, ggplot2, gganimate

I am currently creating a gif which contains large data. I want it in high resolution.

On my old PC it took hours to render and simply wasn't worth it.

My new PC has a very strong intel i9-9900k core processor which has sped it up to about 30 minutes but R only uses 1 core by default... I have 8 available and it would be great if I could just use them to get the rendering done in under 5 minutes. I will be needing to run this multiple times a week so it would be amazing to be able to use all 8 cores.

Is there anyway to take advantage of this? I know you can use multi-threading in some R code but I can't figure it out with ggplot2/gganimate.

I also have a strong graphics card if that can be used in any way to speed this up.

Or if there is any other way to speed it up that you can think of, even if it means changing package or even programming language that would be great!

Comment: it is planned : https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/78

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper That is good to hear! It would be very useful to a lot of people as rendering is a CPU intensive process and many people have multicores. I expect it won't be out of the planned stage for a while but if it does get updated soon I hope I'll notice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage parallel processing with animated ggplot2-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697548/how-to-manage-parallel-processing-with-animated-ggplot2-plot)

Answer (score 2):

As Roman pointed out in the comments, there is a pull request to facilitate parallell processing of animated ggplots.

Here is an example with a benchmark, from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/78#issuecomment-689855700)

```r
library(gganimate)

anim <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

future::plan("sequential")  ## default
t0 <- system.time(animate(anim))
print(t0)

future::plan("multiprocess", workers = 4L)
t1 <- system.time(animate(anim))
print(t1)

print(t0 / t1)
##      user    system   elapsed 
## 2.2802385 0.9121339 2.5819751
```

The pull request has yet to be merged, but if you need this now you can install that particular fork with `devtools::install_github()`

This is much easier than [what has previously been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50702959/3212698)

Comment: For more details of how to put this in practice, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321487/how-to-use-multiple-cores-to-make-gganimate-faster.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the encoding step will be much faster and much better quality by using a proper modern video format instead of gif. For example:

```
animate(anim, fps = 25, renderer = av_renderer("out.mkv"))
```

This uses the the av package, which has multihreaded high definition encoders.

Comment: is there a benchmark test proving this? I tried to compare the 2 renderers (`av_renderer()` and `gifski_renderer`) and the rendering duration is exactly the same with my data (unfortunately cannot share the data for the sake of confidentiality). But I would like to see this comparison on different data sets and this could potentially help me find some bugs in my code in case there is indeed a difference in the rendering duration :)